# DialogFragment does not close in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a way to check the Internet connection every 15 seconds. If there is no internet connection, the method calls the dialogfragment. So far it works perfectly. I cannot close dialogFragment when internet connection is established. Logcat does not give an error.  "dialogfragment dissmis" not working and dialogfragment remains on the screen.

First I disconnect from the internet and the dialogFragment is called. Later  Internet connection is running and "Device is connected to internet." I see the text. But the dialogfragment does not disappear.

**CheckInternetAsyncTask.class**

```
public class CheckInternetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {


    Activity activity;
    private Context context;



    public CheckInternetAsyncTask(Activity activity) {
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        assert cm != null;
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnected();

        if (isConnected) {
            try {
                InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com");
                //You can replace it with your name
                return !ipAddr.equals("");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error checking internet connection"+ e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            //Log.d("TAG", "No network available!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Log.d("TAG", "result" + result);

        if(result){
            // do ur code
            Toast.makeText(context,"Device is connected to internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            EthernetControlFragment ethernetControlFragment = EthernetControlFragment.newInstance();

            if (ethernetControlFragment != null
                    && ethernetControlFragment.getDialog() != null
                    && ethernetControlFragment.getDialog().isShowing()
                    && !ethernetControlFragment.isRemoving()) {
                //dialog is showing so do something
                ethernetControlFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
            } else {
                //dialog is not showing
            }

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context,"Device is not connected to internet!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            EthernetControlFragment ethernetControlFragment = EthernetControlFragment.newInstance();

            if (ethernetControlFragment != null
                    && ethernetControlFragment.getDialog() != null
                    && ethernetControlFragment.getDialog().isShowing()
                    && !ethernetControlFragment.isRemoving()) {
                //dialog is showing so do something
            } else {
                //dialog is not showing
                ethernetControlFragment.show(((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager(), "ethernet");
                ethernetControlFragment.setCancelable(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**EthernetControlFragment**

```
public class EthernetControlFragment extends DialogFragment {

Context context;

public static EthernetControlFragment newInstance(){
    return new EthernetControlFragment();
}



@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.dogum_haritasi_dialog);

}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ethernet_controls,container,false);

    return view;
}}
```

Comment: are you calling this AsyncTask every 15 seconds to show no internet dialog is internet is not connected?

Comment: Yes. is constantly checking.

Comment: i think issue is because you're creating new dialog object every time so even if you close a dialog when internet is connected it's new object whereas old Dialog fragment is still being shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Call fragment like this:

```
    Fragment prev = ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ethernet");
    if (prev == null) {
        ethernetControlFragment.show(((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager(), "ethernet");
        ethernetControlFragment.setCancelable(false);
    }
```

And dissmis like this:

```
Fragment prev = ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ethernet");
            if (prev != null) {
                EthernetControlFragment df = (EthernetControlFragment) prev;
                df.dismiss();
            }
```

I think these methods are the most reliable way to call and dissmis fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i'm gonna explain here in detail.

15 seconds ago you created a dialog using below line let's call it `object1`

`EthernetControlFragment.newInstance()`

Then after 15 seconds again you're creating a new dialog `object2` using above line and when you're dismissing it you're dismissing this new dialog `object2`. Unfortunately you're not keeping reference of old Dialog `dialog1` which is the real issue.

Solution would be to create only one object so create a global reference of `EthernetControlFragment` class and initialise this only if it's null. This way you'll have only one dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. i use  if(ethernetControlFragment == null){
            EthernetControlFragment ethernetControlFragment = EthernetControlFragment.newInstance();
        } but not work :(

Comment: i suggested keeping global reference assuming you kept your as AsyncTask in Activity. My bad, otherwise i would have suggested the one you used. Anyway issue was basically not keeping one dialog object.

Comment: I solved my problem by taking advantage of your answer. Thank you.